# Convolution between modified Bessel function and sinc function

Tags: convolution, bessel-functions

Would it be possible to calculate the following convolution analytically
$$
       K_0(\xi r) * \frac{\sin(r)}{r},
$$
where $K_0$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind and $*$ denotes convolution.

Thanking you!

Wang Zhe

Comment: What have you tried so far, dear :)

Comment: Hi @Nosrati, I am trying to solving this problem [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043769/bessel-integral-invovling-algebraic-and-hyperbolic-functions), and was wondering if it can be simplified to the current one. I am not sure if I am on the right track, please, could you point me out. Thank you!

Comment: Is the convolution a 1D convolution, or a 2D convolution of 2 circularly symmetric functions?

Comment: Merry Christmas! It would be a 2D convolution with circular symmetry.